# Question on Linear Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

The following question is modified from an exercise in chapter 3 in Linear Algebra by Hoffman and Kunze (2nd ed.):

Let
 $V$
 be an 
$n$-dimensional vector space over a field $F$ and let 
$T$ be a linear transformation from 
$V$
 to
 $V$ such that its range and kernel are identical.

a) Prove that 
$n$
 is even

b) Give an example to such a linear transformation when $n=2$.

I proved the first part using $\text{nullity}-\text{rank}$ theorem and arrived at $2\text{rank}(T)=n$ which means that $2$ divides $n$ and so $n$ is even.
However proving the second part proved abortive to me. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make $T(e_2)=e_1$, $T(e_1)=0$. It is obvious that the given linear transformation satisfies the required property.

> If you want matrix form, note that it will be $M_T =\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.$

> "It is my experience that proofs involving matrices can be shortened by 50% if one throws the matrices out."
> -Emil Artin, Geometric Algebra

Comment: can you elaborate please??

Comment: On what, specifically?

Comment: Your answer, it really looks helpful but it's kinda short. Which one is the transformation specifically? How can see that the kernel and the range are identical?

Comment: Note that for the transformation $T$ I defined, $T(ae_1+be_2)=be_1.$ Since this holds for every $a,b$, the image is precisely the subspace $\{b e_1 \mid b \in \mathbb{R} \}$. That is to say, the "horizontal line" in $\mathbb{R}^2$. 

Now, since $T(ae_1+be_2)=be_1,$  we have that $T(ae_1+be_2)=0$ iff $b=0$. So, the kernel is $\{ae_1 \mid a \in \mathbb{R}\}$. Hence, the kernel and image are identical.

Comment: It looks better now, I find it really helpful. But lastly, what would be my vector space then?    $$R^2$$?

Comment: @YYG Yes.${}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $\vec{v}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$ generates the image.  Since $A\vec{v}=\vec{0}$, then with $A=\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$ we know that $A\vec{v}=\begin{bmatrix}a\\c\end{bmatrix}$ so $a=c=0$.  On the other hand, since the image of $\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}$ must be a multiple of $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$ (as this vector generates the image of the map defined by $A$), you must have $A\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}b\\d\end{bmatrix}$ a multiple of $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$.  In other words, $d=0$.

Comment: I did not fully understand @Michael, is there any way u can make it more clearer for me?? Thanks.

Comment: Okay. Then how can I see that the range and the kernel are identical from the example and why are we interested in having $$a,b,c,d$$ all being 0?

Comment: We have $a$, $c$, and $d$ are all zero because those come from the conditions / set-up that only multiples of $\vec{v}$ are in the image and that $A\vec{v}=0$.